# Javascript error in every page on IE 10

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer-10

My asp.net site is running well on IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9, Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera. But it is not working at all in IE10.

If I click anywhere in the site (any button, any link, etc) it returns the following error:

```
SCRIPT5022: Sys.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Value must be an integer.
Parameter name: x
Actual value was 5.999999523162842.
```

JS things, like tabs, doesnt work due to this problem. I tracked down the problem and it is in MicrosoftAjax.js , specifically in the following method.

```
Sys.UI.Point = function Sys$UI$Point(x, y) {
    /// <param name="x" type="Number" integer="true"></param>
    /// <param name="y" type="Number" integer="true"></param>
    /// <field name="x" type="Number" integer="true"></field>
    /// <field name="y" type="Number" integer="true"></field>
    var e = Function._validateParams(arguments, [
        {name: "x", type: Number, integer: true},
        {name: "y", type: Number, integer: true}
    ]);
    if (e) throw e;

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
```

It works on all other IE versions since 6, which is quite a fate.

**I know that HTML is only supported by real browsers, leaving out Internet Explorer**, but my client really wants the site to work in IE10.

Just to be clear, it works well in ie6 to 9, chrome, firefox and opera. None of them show javascript errors, just ie10, and this error comes up on every click. 
I copule not track who is calling this method. This is a big site and none of the js code that i use is calling it. I think that probably MicrosoftAjax.js framework has bound the click event and it is executing something but i am not sure what it is executing.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you just round the numbers (or cast them as integers with `parseInt()`) prior to calling your function?

Comment: Did you debug it? Why is a float  being passed? -1 for not showing due dilligence. It could be because you are multiplying or dividing numbers and getting into precision problems, if so just round the number

Comment: This sort of thing usually happens to me when I have a broken jQuery plugin or bad JavaScript code. Do you have anything on the page that uses Ajax? Do you see any code that has a reference to something that isn't there? If you view the page in Firefox or Chrome,  do you see any errors when you hit `Control-Shift-J`?

Comment: I could not track who is calling that methods. I am not calling they, it is something internal of MicrosoftAjax.js i think

Comment: Also, Neither firebug nor chrome is showing javascript errors. IE9 developer tools doesnt show javascript errors.

Comment: Are you using iFrames?  This block of code has caused some troubles before, especially on pages with iFrames.  http://forums.asp.net/t/1078598.aspx/1. Also: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936993

Comment: Thanks Maurice, your comment makes sense, I will try later and let you know. It can be related to the use of iframes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in the following link:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936993

I had to change Microsoft.Ajax.js.

Comment: I'm kind of sad I'm not the only one that's still running ASP.NET 2.0 projects with Microsoft Ajax Extensions 1.0...I feel your pain man.

Comment: Thanks Justin, it's a pain, really.

Comment: The KB article was helpful as a starting point, but after their coding changes I was still getting the error. I ended up changing it further with Math.round().

Comment: It's 2017, and I'm working on .net 4.0 webforms.,  this organization can only bandage the application for so long., but until then thanks for these answers.

Answer (score 19):

I found a nice [solution](http://codecorner.galanter.net/2013/05/01/solution-for-ie10-error-script5022-sys-argumentoutofrangeexception-value-must-be-an-integer/) blogged by [Yuriy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961695/yuriy-galanter):

```
<script language="javascript">
    Sys.UI.Point = function Sys$UI$Point(x, y) {

        x = Math.round(x);
        y = Math.round(y);

        var e = Function._validateParams(arguments, [
            {name: "x", type: Number, integer: true},
            {name: "y", type: Number, integer: true}
        ]);
        if (e) throw e;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
</script>
```

Paste this on your page to override the Sys$UI$Point function to round the numbers.

Or, set `<compilation debug="false">`

Either of these worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to [mafu josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119418/mafu-josh)'s answer, the bound prototype can also be the issue.

Here's the code for that

```
Sys.UI.Bounds = function Sys$UI$Bounds(x, y, width, height) {
    x = Math.round(x);
    y = Math.round(y);

    var e = Function._validateParams(arguments, [
        { name: "x", type: Number, integer: true },
        { name: "y", type: Number, integer: true },
        { name: "width", type: Number, integer: true },
        { name: "height", type: Number, integer: true }
    ]);
    if (e) throw e;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
}
```

Comment: I faced this issue with Telerik RadDock & RadWindow. Able to solve with this code. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue; resolved after following the solution posted here by nileshsaikhede
http://forums.asp.net/t/1884400.aspx/1

All I had to do was add

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

to my master page.

Comment: I didnt try this, and I wont, since it is fixed and I dont want to mess anything up, but if I had to fix it today, I would give this a shot. Thanks Alex.

Comment: This is really a bad fix as it might not work in IE 11, it would be much better to fix the real issue when running in standards mode.

Comment: @Lavinski - yes the best option is to fix the real issue, if you have time and there is a solution. I found this hours before my deployment and my management didn't want me to postpone the deployment, and I couldn't find a fix for my issue. This is just an alternate quick fix.

Comment: content="IE=edge" doesn not fix this issue or in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the one option. I have modified the `MicrosoftAjax.js` and `MicrosoftAjax.debug.js` file for rounding the point value before returning `Sys.UI.Point` for all areas - see as below.

```
    if (typeof param1 === "number")
    {
        param1 = Math.round(param1);
    }

    if (typeof param2 === "number")
    {
        param2 = Math.round(param2);
    }

    return new Sys.UI.Point(param1, param2);
```

I have referenced modified js file using Script option in ScriptManager code of ASPX page. That's how it is done.

I hope it helps other.

Answer (score 0):

if your using internet explorer then 
press **ALT** 
select Tools -----> Compatibility View -------> then add your website to be displayed in Compatibility.
hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="requiresActiveX=true" />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please write your answer in English, as StackOverflow is an [English only site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/6126373).